# Implementation of Multiple Parallel interface

Tags: java

Suppose I have an interface defined as:

```
public interface TestInterface1 {
    public void add();
}
```

which is implemented by classes A, B and C.

Now I need to add a subtract functionality *only* to class C; for that I have created a new interface `TestInterface2` and implemented that to class C:

```
public interface TestInterface2 {
    public void sub();
}
```

Class C looks like this:

```
public class C implements TestInterface1, TestInterface2 {
    public void add() {
        System.out.println("I am in add");
    }

    public void sub() {
        System.out.println("I am in Sub");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is instances of C has been use in hundreds of places like this:

```
TestInterface1 c = new C();
```

And only class C is getting the add method of `TestInterface1`.

Is there any way or pattern to implement both the interfaces in class C so that where ever the object of class C is created, it gets both the method from `TestInterface1` and `TestInterface2`?

Comment: If it is `java 8` then you can use `default methods`

Comment: else extend one interface by another and then it may be done.Hope it makes sense

Comment: `C c = new C();`?

Comment: If I go for C c = new C(); I have to change it in all the 100 places where the object of C is used

Comment: Why would you need to change it everywhere?  Just change it where you need access to `sub()`.  All the places where you only use `add()` can be left alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your interfaces then make TestInterface1 extend the other one, so object created using first interface can use its parent methods.

```
public interface TestInterface1 extends  TestInterface2{
   public void add();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we get into this, you have to consider why you're even using interfaces for this at all.  An interface guarantees that all instances are using the same implementations.  If you want a specific class to have a more specific implementation, then that sounds more like a method on the concrete class more than it does a new interface at all.

Regardless, we can discuss your options. One of them is cleaner and conveys clear intent; the other muddies things.

The first option - which conveys clearer intent - is to eschew the usage of the more restrictive interface and instead use `TestInterface2` for every declaration that you want to use `C`.

This means you'd write `TestInterface2 c = new C();` everywhere you wanted to use it.  Yes, you'd be changing it in all of the places that you're using `C`, but given that you have to have a method specifically attached to instances of `C`, this option is clearest.

This would be the same approach if you just wrote the method in `C`.  There's really no difference between the two and I personally would prefer if you wrote the method that *only* belonged to `C` in `C`.

The second option - which muddies things and also requires Java 8 - is to use a default method.  This *requires* that you implement it in the interface at first...

```
public interface TestInterface {
    default void sub() {
        System.out.println("I am in sub!");
    }
}
```

...but you can override it in your class later.  This muddies things because *any* class that implements `TestInterface` has access to this default method, which is likely not what you want for your requirements.